# What execute RUN instruction in exec mode

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a Dockerfile, RUN instruction has two forms `shell` and `exec`:

```
# shell form
RUN <command>

# exec form 
RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"]
```

When shell form is used the `<command>` is run inside a shell, prepending to it a proper shell (i.e.: `sh -c "<command>"`).
So far so good, the question is: how exec form work? How commands are executed without shell? I haven't found a satisfying answer reading official doc.

Comment: @cdarke: I believe the OP might be referring to `docker`; it uses `run` for commands it executes.

Comment: Yes, pardon, I meant Dockerfile...

Answer (score 1):

The exec form of the command runs your command with the same OS syscall that Docker would use to run the shell itself. It's just doing the namespaced version of a fork/exec that linux uses to run any process. The shell itself is a convenience that provides PATH handling, variable expansion, IO redirection, and other scripting features, but these aren't required to run processes at the OS level. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179604/171859) may help you understand how Linux runs processes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a docker file.

With the RUN syntax, the commands will run one at a time in the para virtualised environment and the default shell for the given environment (usually Bash) will be spawned for each command. sh -c is "short-hand" for bash and so you are in effect doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In shell form, the command will run inside a shell with /bin/sh –c

```
RUN apt-get update
```

Exec format allows execution of command in images that don’t have /bin/sh

```
RUN [“apt-get”, “update”]
```

shell form is easier to write and you can perform shell parsing of variables
• For example

```
CMD sudo -u $(USER} java ....
```

• Exec form does not require image to have a shell.

Comment: This type of info are in official doc. The question is that part: _"Exec format allows execution of command in images that don’t have /bin/sh"_ But if image haven't /bin/sh how command are executed???